# Will deleting a user remove all of their saved data?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am playing on a used 3DS I just bought - if I delete the old user of the previous owner, will it get rid of the saved data for the games?

Answer (score 2):

No, deleting the old user will not reset the game.

The save for Pokemon X/Y is stored on the game itself. Luckily, you can reset it by pressing up on the D-pad + B + X simultaneously on the title screen.

Source: [GameFAQ Forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/696959-pokemon-x/answers/360779-can-i-delete-my-save-data)

Comment: Just for completion: Is this also true for the non-cardridge version?

Comment: I don't know. Everything I find indicates that it's the same for the digital version.

Comment: @Trollwut IIRC you shouldn't be able to play a downloaded content if you deactivate the associated Nintendo ID.